# jQuery: changing div placement based on browser width

Tags: jquery, resize, css-selectors

I have 28 divs, all floated left with a width & height of 200px with 5px margins on the right and bottom of each div. I have successfully figured out how to place other divs after other divs via jquery. I did it like so.

`$( '.inner:nth-child(10)' ).after( '<div class="test">');`

This works great! But what I would like to do is change the "inner" div classes nth-child position based on browser width and I've managed to get it working, somewhat.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var $window = $(window);

function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize > 440) {
     $( '.inner:nth-child(10)' ).after( '<div class="test">');
    }
}

// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

So I'm telling my browser to display the div "inner" after the 10th "test" div when the viewers browser width exceeds 440px. Again, this works, somewhat. It successfully displays the "inner" div in the correct position when the browser width exceeds 440px, and it also doesn't show the div when the browser width is below 440px. But the huge problem is that whenever the window is resized, a whole bunch of divs start to be created. This is very puzzling to me. Here is the jsFiddle to demonstrate my issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/EUqEm/2/

You will see that at a glance it appears to be working fine but if you resize the HTML window within jsfiddle, a bunch of divs start to be created. In actuality, the div should always remain in the correct spot, right after the 10th inner div. Instead, it just creates a bunch of other divs when the window is resized.

If anyone could help me out with a solution to this problem and get this little issue working properly within jsfiddle, it would mean a ton to me! :)

Comment: Just a note, in your `checkWidth` method you're using: `var windowSize = $window.width();` That should be `var windowSize = $(window).width();` (you missed the brackets around `window` :)

Comment: Everytime your window is resized it will call your checkwidth method and as you have no test to see if your divs are created already, it will just recreate them.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I'm not that great at jquery (yet) and I don't know how to go about a solution regarding your comment. it would be awesome if you could provide an answer with a jsfiddle for a fix to my problem.  Thanks for informing me though.

Comment: you could call something like `$('.inner').remove()` at the beginning of the function so it removes any previous divs first before creating the new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
    var $window = $(window);
var resized=false;
function checkWidth() {

    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize > 440) {
        //if the window is greater than 440px wide then place the "inner" div after the 10th "test" div
        if(resized==false){
     $( '.inner:nth-child(10)' ).after( '<div class="test">');
            resized=true;
        }
    }
     if (windowsize <= 440) {
         $('.test').remove();
         resized=false;
     }
}
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Is this what you wanted? In your version the resize function is calling .after() many times, adding a lot of new divs. It should work this way

EDIT:
With @pete s suggestion it's easyer to add new colored divs.

```
    var $window = $(window);

function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize > 440) {
        //if the window is greater than 440px wide then place the "inner" div after the 10th "test" div
        $('.test').remove();
     $( '.inner:nth-child(10)' ).after( '<div class="test">');
    }else{
        $('.test').remove();
    }
    if (windowsize > 500) {
        //if the window is greater than 440px wide then place the "inner" div after the 10th "test" div
        $('.test1').remove();
     $( '.inner:nth-child(12)' ).after( '<div class="test1">');
    }else{
         $('.test1').remove();
    }
}
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

You just have to add the css rule for the test1 class.

Comment: surely this negates the resize function as it will only fire once when a window is resized and then never again so you won't have the final window size

Comment: Pete, everything seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EUqEm/8/ let me know if you notice any errors.

Comment: Well actually it's called again after the windowsize gets from <=440 to >440. This is all it needs to do if I got what Dyck wanted.

Comment: @CosLu hey man I'm trying to get this working so that I can do multiple browser sizes.. so I'd like to display a div in one position if the browser side exceeds 440px then insert another div in a different position when the browser exceeds 740px. I tried doing it here: http://jsfiddle.net/EUqEm/9/ but it isn't working for some reason.  Do you think you could get that jsfiddle to work properly with multiple div positions for different browser widths? that would be amazing!!! :)

Comment: @Dyck it's because you're sharing the same control variables. Just add and repeat the same thing if you want to add another colored div. http://jsfiddle.net/EUqEm/23/ (in this example i addedd 500px instead of 740 just for testing)

Comment: @CosLu works great, thanks a lot man you've really helped me out a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that your solution has no state. It does not know if you are transitioning to a sub-440 width or if you are already narrower than that. Consequently, each time the resize triggers you add another div. For this simple use case I'd suggest checking for the existence of your test div before adding it.

Not sure if it's what you intend but it might be worth removing the test div if the width is greater than 440 too.